# Closure of subspace of $\ell^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I need to compute the closure of the following subspace of $\ell^2$:
$$\mathsf X := \left\{x \in \ell^2\ \Bigg|\  \sum_{n\in\Bbb N} n^2 |x_n|^2<+\infty\right\}. $$
My intuition tells me that the border $\partial\mathsf X$ should contain sequences like $(1/n)_n$, and more generally $(\alpha_n/n)_n$, where $\alpha_n\in\Bbb S^1\subset\Bbb C$ (which appears to be the image of $(1/n)_n$ under an arbitrary unitary operator on $\ell^2$). However, I wouldn't know how to show that these are the only limit points of $\mathsf X$. Any ideas?

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n,0,0,\cdots) \to (x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. What can you conclude from this?

Comment: $\overline {\mathsf X} = \ell^2$?

Comment: Yes, that is the answer.